# freebsd ignores service startup

Tags: startup, freebsd, opnsense

I installed 3proxy on freebsd(11.2-RELEASE-p10-HBSD FreeBSD ) which is whith opnsense from ports, but I cannot autoload it after restart
service 3proxy start - works nice
I make /usr/local/etc/rc.d/3proxy 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    653 Feb 26 20:35 3proxy

```
#!/bin/sh
# $FreeBSD: head/net/3proxy/files/3proxy.in 340872 2014-01-24 00:14:07Z mat $

# PROVIDE: threeproxy
# REQUIRE: DAEMON
# BEFORE: LOGIN
# KEYWORD: shutdown

# Define these threeproxy_* variables in one of these files:
#       /etc/rc.conf
#       /etc/rc.conf.local
#       /etc/rc.conf.d/threeproxy
#
# DO NOT CHANGE THESE DEFAULT VALUES HERE

threeproxy_enable=${threeproxy_enable-"NO"}
threeproxy_flags=${threeproxy_flags-"/usr/local/etc/3proxy.cfg"}

. /etc/rc.subr

name="threeproxy"
rcvar=threeproxy_enable
command="/usr/local/bin/3proxy"

load_rc_config $name

start_cmd="echo \"Starting ${name}.\";  ${command} ${threeproxy_flags} &"

run_rc_command "$1"
```

then added line here `/etc/rc.conf`

```
threeproxy_enable="YES"
```

But after restart I also see that service is down - how can I do this?

I also thought about crontab and @reboot. 
Please help me

Comment: It probably fails to start. Look for its logs, or try starting it in foreground to see if there are any error messages.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/3proxy /usr/local/etc/3proxy.cfg` works? probably chack the stdout outpout, config logs

Comment: yes it works! I installed today new opnense and installed from ports 3proxy< put line in  /etc/rc.conf - after restart it is not running... what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can it be because "monitor" in 3proxy looks on 3 files whithout versioning? I'm monitoring ip's of 3 interfaces